# Why does my favorite count vary on my profile?

Tags: support, bookmarks, favorites-notifications, favorites-tab

Whenever I read a nice question, I used to mark it as a favorite question. Today, while I was looking at my profile's favorite section, it was as follows:

[image]

Why does my favorite count vary on my profile? Is it a bug, or am I missing something with respect to the favorite section of my profile? I marked the areas causing confusion with circle in the picture.

Kindly clarify

Comment: Hi Lonely. I'll migrate this to the Stack Exchange meta as it will be an implementation bug or feature

Comment: What is that bizarre OS you're running there?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The count shows the number of comments and new or edited answers on your favourite question, not the number of favourites you have.